# Get vertical labels to be close together

Tags: actionscript-3, layout, flex3

I cant quite understand why two vertical label components dont appear right under each other. There seems to be a lot of space between them, is there anyway to get this space removed as setting padding makes no difference at all.

For example, take this layout code:

```
<mx:VBox>
<mx:Label text="Title" paddingBottom="0" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0" />
<mx:Label text="Second bit of text I want to appear right under the first" paddingBottom="0" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0" />
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `VBox`'s `verticalGap` to 0 or a suitable value.

Comment: I found "verticalGap" on a VBox component, its much better (setting it to 0) but still not perfect. Also I cant seem to add this property to a programmatically created component: "var contentLinkBox:VBox = new VBox();"

Comment: Aha, you set it as a style: contentLinkBox.setStyle("verticalGap", 0);

Answer (score 0):

Margin = 0?

Comment: I cant seem to add 'margin' to a text or label component